# Mongoose Refs to children

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am struggling to find examples or documentation on mongoose children population.

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

On the documentation they have:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , Schema = mongoose.Schema

var personSchema = Schema({
  _id     : Number,
  name    : String,
  age     : Number,
  stories : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' }]
});

var storySchema = Schema({
  _creator : { type: Number, ref: 'Person' },
  title    : String,
  fans     : [{ type: Number, ref: 'Person' }]
});

var Story  = mongoose.model('Story', storySchema);
var Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);
```

It makes sense, a Person can have many stories thus the 'parent' field 'stories' which has a list of all the stories in.

What I am struggling to understand is how do you push the the story into the person schema.

For example, i have an **assignment schema**:

```
var mongoose      = require ( 'mongoose' ),
    Schema        = mongoose.Schema;

var assignmentSchema = new Schema (
    {
        _id: String,
        assignName: String,
        modInsID: [{ type: Schema.Types.Number, ref: 'ModuleInst' }],
        studentAssigns: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'StudentAssign' }]
    }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model ( 'Assignment', assignmentSchema );
```

The `studentAssigns` stores all the id's of the `studentAssigns` which then can be used with the `.pre` middleware for cascade deleting.

So now my StudentAssign schema:

```
var mongoose      = require ( 'mongoose' ),
    autoIncrement = require ( 'mongoose-auto-increment' ),
    Schema        = mongoose.Schema;

var connection = mongoose.createConnection("************");
autoIncrement.initialize(connection);


var studentAssignSchema = new Schema (
    {
        assID: [{ type: Schema.Types.String, ref: 'Assignment' }],
        studentID: [{ type: Schema.Types.Number, ref: 'Student' }]
    }
);

var StudentAssign = connection.model('StudentAssign', studentAssignSchema);
module.exports = mongoose.model ('StudentAssign', studentAssignSchema );
```

As you can see it already is referencing '`Assignment`'

Here is my api code:

studentAssign POST:

```
router.route('/student-assignment').post( function(req, res) {
    var studentAssign = new StudentAssign();
    studentAssign.assID = req.body.assID;
    studentAssign.studentID = req.body.studentID;

    studentAssign.save(function(err, studentAssign) {
        if(err) console.log(err);
        res.status(200).json(studentAssign);
    });
})
```

So that's the part I am confused at where would I push the '`studentAssign`' into '`Assignment`' schema's '`studentAssigns` array ??

here is my current api json callback:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "As 1",
    "assignName": "Software Implementation",
    "__v": 0,
    "studentAssigns": [],
    "modInsID": [
      {
        "_id": 22,
        "semester": "TRI 3",
        "year": 2016,
        "__v": 0,
        "modID": [
          111
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The documentation just does not make it clear as they just show:

`aaron.stories.push(story1);
aaron.save(callback);`

With no explanation?

I have attempted:

`var assignment = new Assignment();
assignment.studentAssigns.push(studentAssign);` and nothing gets stored ??

Comment: Did you call assignment.save(); ?

Comment: @Molda yup sorry i didn't copy that part in

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example based on the documentation [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const personSchema = Schema({
   _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
   name: String,
   age: Number,
   stories: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' }]
});

const storySchema = Schema({
author: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' },
title: String,
fans: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' }]
});

const Story = mongoose.model('Story', storySchema);
const Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);
```

`Person` model has its `stories` field set to an array of `ObjectId`'s

For saving **Refs to children** you may have first to save stories before pushing them to `Person`'s `stories` field

```
const story1 = new Story({
title: 'Casino Royale',
author: author._id    // assign the _id from the person
});
story1.save();
```

And before pushing `story1` find the **author id** you want to push to

```
const author = await Person.findOne({_id: "624313f302e268b597b8df1f"}) 

if(Array.isArray(author.stories)) author.stories.push(story1);

author.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

You model states :

```
assID: [{ type: Schema.Types.String, ref: 'Assignment' }],
studentID: [{ type: Schema.Types.Number, ref: 'Student' }]
```

I think from your code you don't want to store multiple assignments in assID and multiple Students in studentID. Modify your model to

```
assID: { type: Schema.Types.String, ref: 'Assignment' },
studentID: { type: Schema.Types.Number, ref: 'Student' }
```

Your save code can stay the same.

If you do want to store for example multiple assignments, you need to push them into the assID array ;-)

Answer (score -1):

```
router.get('/author', (req, res, next) => {
  Person. 
  find().
  exec( (err, person) => {
    if (err) return handleError(err) 
    Story.find({author: person[0]._id}).
    exec( (err, story) => {
      if (err) return handleError(err) 
        person[0].stories.push(story[0])
      res.json( { person: person })
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: Please add some explanatory text to your answer. Why and how does this fix the OP's problem?